# How to separate a string to many elements in nested array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have a string from tab delimited file (with carriage return and newline)

```
"a\taa\taaa\r\nb\tbb\tbbb\r\nc\tcc\tccc"
```

I want to convert this string into an array like

```
[["a","aa","aaa"],["b","bb","bbb"],["c","cc","ccc"]]
```

Now I already did `.scan(/(.+?)\r\n/)` but I still got only

```
[["a\taa\taaa"],["b\tbb\tbbb"],["c\tcc\tccc"]]
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). How are you getting the string? Using the CSV class should make this very easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tend to use [`CSV#parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse) for things like this, since the parsing code is easy to understand:

```
CSV.parse("a\taa\taaa\r\nb\tbb\tbbb\r\nc\tcc\tccc", col_sep: "\t")
=> [["a", "aa", "aaa"], ["b", "bb", "bbb"], ["c", "cc", "ccc"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split) and [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map)?

```
s = "a\taa\taaa\r\nb\tbb\tbbb\r\nc\tcc\tccc"

s.split("\r")  # split by \r (bigger chunks)
=> ["a\taa\taaa", "\nb\tbb\tbbb", "\nc\tcc\tccc"]

s.split("\r").map { |x| x.split }  # Split bigger chunks by spaces (including \t)
=> [["a", "aa", "aaa"], ["b", "bb", "bbb"], ["c", "cc", "ccc"]]
```